# Django request data has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django, jwt

Code:

```
class UserDetailsAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.content_type)
        data=request.data
        user = data.object.get('user') or request.user
        token = data.object.get('access')
        response_data = {
            'access': token,
            'user': UserSer(user).data
        }
        response = Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        if api_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE:
            expiration = (datetime.utcnow() +
                        api_settings.JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA)
            response.set_cookie(api_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE,
                                response.data['access'],
                                expires=expiration,
                                httponly=True)
        return response
```

Error:

```
AttributeError at /api/userdetails/
'dict' object has no attribute 'object'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userdetails/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'dict' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `data.object.get('user')` has no attribute `object`, just write `data.get('user')`